# "Nominate for reopening?" modal is not closed on "Vote to reopen"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

Recently, in the "Reopen votes" queue a new modal was introduced for "are you sure to vote to reopen?" dialog:

[image]

The thing is, it behaves in an unexpected way (at least in Vivaldi 2.9, a Chromium-based browser): if I press "Vote to reopen", the next question to review is shown, but the modal is not closed. Haven't investigated any further yet, but clearly looks like a bug. Comments on (not?)reproducing in other browsers are welcome.

Comment: Can reproduce that on Firefox 70. When clicking on "reopen" the modal opens, the review switches back to tab "Question (revised)" and after clicking "Vote to reopen" the review is done, but the dialog stays open. There is also no issue reported in the developer console in the browser.

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338097/new-dialog-box-in-reopen-votes-review-queue-doesnt-close and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338392/review-queue-pop-up-wont-dismiss-nominate-this-question-for-reopening

Comment: @samcarter yeah, I only searched Meta.SO, not Meta.SE, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Turns out this was broken on question pages as well, but there we reload the page so the dialog *looks* like it closes.

I pushed a fix up into the build pipeline. It'll go into production with the next build. Thanks for the report!

Comment: nice, thanks. Let me wait for it in production before I accept the answer